# How to put an item on DynamoDB table using AWS SDK for Node.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a DynamoDB table named MYTABLE. I'm trying to insert some data into this table via LambdaEdge.

My Lambda function is triggered via a CloudFront Distribution.

I have this function:

```
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
    var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
        var params = {
            TableName: 'MYTABLE',
            Item: {
              'id' : {'S': 'something'},
              'value' : {'S': 'something'}
            }
        };
          
          // Call DynamoDB to add the item to the table
        await ddb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Success", data);
            }
        });

        const response = {
            status: '302',
            statusDescription: 'Found',
            headers: {
                location: [{
                    key: 'Location',
                    value: 'https://www.google.com',
                }],
            },
        };
        return response;
    };
```

The function runs properly (the redirection works) but no data is inserted into the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions on your Lambda -- you can do this in the Console by going to the Lambda function, and then its permissions tab.  Ensure the lambda has [permission to write to the DyanmoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html).

Comment: @SethE thanks for your comment. But according to my knowledge when there is a permissions problem, the function crashes. Isn't ?

Comment: Yeah, the `ddb.putItem` would fail triggering your `err`  branch.  But since it is silently failing in your case, maybe the error is being swallowed somewhere. It does not hurt to check the permissions

Comment: @ThomasCarlton You're method swallows any errors or successes from putItem and carries on to return your canned response.  Are you sure putItem is succeeding?  I would check CloudWatch (if a log group is present) to see if there were any errors or redeploy your lambda to throw an error response in the case of Dynamo failures.

Comment: Hi Thomas ! I think you could try with `await ddb.putItem(params).promise()`, because you're using an async function. And you can put it in a try/catch block to get your logs.